# python else or except to print "invalid command"

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, except

I am kind of new to python and I created a script called py-bot

```
import time, random

prompt = "> "
invalid = "sorry i did not understand."

talk_back_var1 = ["Hello and welcome to 'Talk-Bot'.",
                              "Welcome to 'Py-Bot'."]

talk_back_var2 = ["Very good thanks", "I feel ill....",
                              "Not good", "I don't know"]

def main_chat():
    while True:
        user_input = str(input(prompt)).lower()

        if user_input in["hi", "hello", "yo"]:
            talk_back = random.choice(talk_back_var1)
            print(talk_back)

        elif user_input == "how are you?" or user_input == "how are you":
            talk_back2 = random.choice(talk_back_var2)
            print(talk_back2, "\n", "And you? (good or bad)")

        elif user_input == "good":
            print("ok")
        elif user_input == "bad":
            print("why?")
            input()
            print("Oh ok")

        if user_input in ["quit", "exit"]:
            print("Thanks for using 'Py-Bot'.")
            break

        else:
            print(invalid)


main_chat()
```

but how do I make the `else: print(invalid)` 
work?

when the command is incorrect it works fine but when it is correct it always says "sorry i did not understand."

any help in improving my script?

Comment: Please change the last if to elif.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the last `if` into `elif`:

```
elif user_input in ["quit", "exit"]:
```

otherwise *anything that isn't `quit` or `exit`* will trigger your invalid text.